# Thread.sleep() not working as it should

Tags: java, oop

I'm a beginner in java and i've been trying to implement the Thread.sleep() but it doesn't seem to work correctly. I have included the program which runs and can be tested correctly. This is just a recreated version of the actual program I am actually making. I have just made it simpler with less code

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import java.awt.Color;

public class test extends JFrame implements ActionListener {


private JButton btnHideTable ;
private JLabel initial;
private JLabel second;
private JLabel last;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    test window = new test();
    window.setVisible(true);
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public test() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {

    setTitle("Testing");
    setSize(700,400);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);




            btnHideTable = new JButton("HIDE TABLE");
            btnHideTable.setBounds(233, 76, 193, 36);
            btnHideTable.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 16));
            getContentPane().add(btnHideTable);

            initial = new JLabel("INITIAL");
            initial.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            initial.setFont(new Font("Trebuchet MS", Font.PLAIN, 24));
            initial.setBounds(202, 136, 269, 57);
            getContentPane().add(initial);

            second = new JLabel("SECOND");
            second.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            second.setForeground(Color.MAGENTA);
            second.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 34));
            second.setBounds(233, 203, 250, 65);
            getContentPane().add(second);

            last = new JLabel("LAST");
            last.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
            last.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            last.setFont(new Font("Traditional Arabic", Font.PLAIN, 45));
            last.setBounds(220, 279, 255, 71);
            getContentPane().add(last);

            btnHideTable.addActionListener(this);

            // Both these labels are not visible when the window launches
            second.setVisible(false);
            last.setVisible(false);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    if(ae.getSource() == btnHideTable){

        // When button is clicked, i want the initial label to be invisible and the secon label be visible

        initial.setVisible(false); //THIS WORKS FINE
        second.setVisible(true); // THIS DOESN'T WORK AS IT SHOULD BECAUSE IT DOESN'T SHOW

        //After 5 seconds, display the last Labe
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            last.setVisible(true);
            second.setVisible(false);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.getMessage();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    }
```

}

Comment: what do you expect it to do?

Comment: Can you explain what doesn't work exactly? Does the sleep not occur? Do you get an exception? Does your computer eject a toast from the CD drive?

Comment: I commented the whole code mate with what i expect to happen

Comment: @Aurasphere I have within the code in comments. Most is in the action perform method

Comment: second.setVisible(true); // THIS DOESN'T WORK AS IT SHOULD BECAUSE IT DOESN'T SHOW This occurs before the sleep, so why is the sleep that doesn't work?

Comment: Then you don't have an issue with `Thread.sleep()` but `second.setVisible()`, please change the question accordingly.

Comment: @Aurasphere the second label should show, then wait 5 seconds the the lastLabel should now show but the secondLabel doesn't show at all

Comment: Expecting the sleep to execute before a line before does not make much sense

Comment: @Aurasphere I thought the issue was with Thread.sleep() because without the Thread.sleep(),  the second label displays fine

Comment: Thread.sleep is being called on the Swing event thread, meaning you're putting this key thread to sleep, the thread responsible for painting the GUI and interacting with the user. This will put your entire GUI to sleep, which is not what you want. Google [Thread sleep and Swing GUI](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site:stackoverflow.com+java+thread+sleep+and+Swing+GUI) to see how common this problem is, and the solution: use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Comment: Even without the sleep second is not displayed. It does not have time to render.

Comment: @Aurasphere: regarding your comment, the sleep doesn't work because it prevents `second.setVisible(true)` from being painted, and thus from displaying. Again, the canonical solution is to use a Swing Timer.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thanks mate